# How to ping sap s4 service endpoint from cloud sdk?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

we are building ping api for one s4 odata service. From scp application we want to call service endpoint at a repeated interval. How to call s4 service endpoint from cloud-sdk.Generated VDM only gives us the operations endpoints.

Revert for more info.

Thanks
Swastik

Comment: Could you give an update if the suggested solutions worked in you scenario?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for late reply. this solution perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `HttpClientAccessor` to obtain a client for your target system and then perform a simple head request towards the service:

```java
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(
                 DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyDestination").asHttp());

final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(
                 new HttpHead(BusinessPartnerService.DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH));

assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

Here I took the `BusinessPartnerService` of S/4HANA Cloud as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is it like a check server availability ping or what do you mean by ping API?

You can use any operation like `getAll()` or `getByKey()` to implement a "ping". It very much depends on your knowledge of the service to identify which exact operation to use to make sure the service behaves as you'd expect.

Do you have a certain OData protocol feature in mind that would help to solve your problem, by the way?

You can find more details on the OData client capabilities [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v4-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/). Also, take a look at [connectivity options](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-http-client).

If you explain more behind what you call ping we might suggest a bit more ideas. It overall seems like the task is beyond what the SDK should do, but more of an implementation detail of certain service infrastructure.

Comment: Hi, I want to implement service availability health check. i am using spring actuator. As our service "up" means the application , DB, and backed S4 system is all are available. for DB and application actuator takes care. in order to check s4 we are building custom health indicator where we want to call a basic service call. for that we need to api. however after vdm generation we cannot see any call to service.

Comment: Yes it is server availability ping. nothing else